# How to do regex match on subset of dotted-notation strings

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match multi-dot-notation expressions
but ignore them if they're in lines where they're:

```
- inside a particular string like 'consts'
- inside a comment
- inside a quoted string
```

So I DON'T want to match anything on these 3 lines

```
a.b.consts.d.e
comment line 'a.b.c.d
quote line "a.b.c.d"
```

But DO want to match parts of these 3 lines

```
asdf a.b.c.d
a.b c.d .e c.d.e
long a.b.c.d.e.f.g
```

I've tried a number lookahead/behind/negatives ideas with partial success but nothing that hits all the conditions at once.

See one regex attempt here, which uses the above description text as the actual text to match against: 
https://regex101.com/r/dSinUs/6

Answer (score 0):

This expression would likely fail in many instances because of `[a-z.\s]*`, but it might provide a different perspective as to how we'd start solving this complicated problem, which yet I'm unsure what might be desired or undesired:

```
^(?!(.*["'])|(.*[a-z]\.consts\.[a-z].*))[a-z.\s]*$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbZD65/1)

Comment: This solution is also great except for that same minor edge case. Thanks to both responders! Now I have plenty to study up on to figure WHY these 2 solution work. :)

Comment: As to the exact usage scenario: we deal with JSON a lot and can drift into the habit of using multi-dot notation w/o actually testing that each object exists. So a reference like "x = a.b.c[0].d" will crash in the language we use if a or a.b or a.b.c doesn't exist, or c isn't an array, or the 0th element doesn't contain a "d". So the regex i'm wanting would be one you'd plug into the IDE like Sublime to search the whole app to help locate such "unsafe" references so we can address them on a case-by-case basis, but skip the ones that are not a threat (like ones in quotes or a comment).

Answer (score 0):

This can help you, it is a little complex but it do the work

```
^\b((?!\.\w{2,}\.)[^"'])+(\s*\w{1}\s*\.)+\w$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dSinUs/7

Comment: Wow, that's great thanks! I feel a little better knowing it was pretty dang complicated after all! The only small issue is if I have "a.b  c.d  e.f" it still matches (unless you put in a trailing space), but for my purposes that's a very minor edge case.

Comment: It will be more easier if you try to do regex match by steps especially if you use c#, then you won't need this complex regex